# wix custom action Configuring Application Pools

Tags: iis, wix, custom-action

I'm trying change application pool for my web application with help custom action

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="ConfigureAppPools" Before="InstallFinalize">Application pool         configured</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>

  <!-- Snip -->                                          
    <CustomAction Id="ConfigureAppPools" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check" Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd set site /site.name:&quot;Default Web Site&quot;/[path='/MyWeb'].applicationPool:MyWeb"/>
```

but get following error
LGHT0204 : ICE03: Invalid format string; Table: CustomAction, Column: Target, Key(s): ConfigureAppPools

How fix ?

Answer (score 4):

You should escape the square brackets in your ExeCommand attribute (those around `path=...`), because otherwise MSI thinks it is a property it must format. Try this:

```
<CustomAction Id="ConfigureAppPools" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check" Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd set site /site.name:&quot;Default Web Site&quot; /[\[]path='/MyWeb'[\]].applicationPool:MyWeb"/>
```

Each square bracket you'd like to escape must be prefixed with backslash, and wrapper into another pair of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

the text `Application pool         configured` is not a valid condition.

See the [Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or some examples [here](http://zacky.cleverits.com/IT/MSI/msi_conditions.htm).